# Change the number of products per page in category view

Tags: magento-1.7

This seems like a totally simple thing, but I just can't figure out how to do it.  I am running on Magento 1.7 and I can not figure out how to set the number of products per page in a category view.

Answer (score 6):

Okay, took one more look and found it at: 
**Admin > System > Configuration > Catalog > Front End**

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to change it is from the configuration tab

System->Configuration-> catalog tab-catalog->frontend you can change it easily from your magento backend.